# Linear Regression Model -Correlation coefficient

Tags: machine-learning-model

I m beginner in ML.I am working on project for predicting trip duration for rental bikes but I dont see any strong co-relation between input variables and target i.e. tripduration when I plot correlation cofficient.
My question is which method of machine learning applies to this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You're faced with a regression problem with (I suppose) labeled data. I can suggest multiple algorithms (multilinear regression, polinomial regression, neural networks...) but it depends on the data.
Plot it, search for correlation, try to extract features.. there is no recipe when it comes to choosing a model.
But, even if you don't end up with the optimal one it's not a big deal, tuning hyperparameters and choosing the features is much more important.

Or you can just try them all if you have the time and patience.